# php json_encode constant implementation

Tags: php, json

I am working with php 5.1 and need to implement `JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION` and `JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR` to encode array as json in this function:

```
function _json_encode($val, $optios=0)
{
if (is_string($val)) return '"'.addslashes($val).'"';
if (is_numeric($val)) return $val;
if ($val === null) return 'null';
if ($val === true) return 'true';
if ($val === false) return 'false';

$assoc = false;
$i = 0;
foreach ($val as $k=>$v){
    if ($k !== $i++){
        $assoc = true;
        break;
    }
}
$res = array();
foreach ($val as $k=>$v){
    $v = _json_encode($v);
    if ($assoc){
        $k = '"'.addslashes($k).'"';
        $v = $k.':'.$v;
    }
    $res[] = $v;
}
$res = implode(',', $res);
return ($assoc)? '{'.$res.'}' : '['.$res.']';
}
```

I am not getting how to add those constants?

Comment: `I am working with php 5.1` Maybe try upgrading PHP to a version that has those constants? [5.1 has been End of Life for 10 years](http://php.net/eol.php)

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but it's well past time to upgrade. 5.1 has been dead for (literally) a decade...

Comment: there should be a way to do this. i have also php 5.6 but i need to implement those in 5.1. with no apps or external environment.